# Updating text component via selectOneMenu from inside a JSF2/Facelets subview

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, facelets, selectonemenu

I have a Facelets **subview** called `basedata-cpanel.xhtml`, which gets its parameters passed via `<ui:param>`s:

```
<ui:define name="content-top">
  <h:form>
    <ui:include src="/subviews/basedata-cpanel.xhtml">
      <ui:param name="customerId"   value="#{pqHome.pq.customer.id}" />
      <ui:param name="customerName" value="#{pqHome.pq.customer.name}" />
      <ui:param name="customers"    value="#{organizationManager.allCustomers}" />        
    <ui:include />
  </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

In the subview, I simply want a panel below to show the currently selected customer name (the panel is for NEW and UPDATE panels/pages). I need an AJAX request for this.

Code in `/subviews/basedata-cpanel.xhtml`:

```
      <h:selectOneMenu value="#{customerId}" id="customer-select">
        <f:selectItems value="#{customers}"
                       var="customer"
                       itemValue="#{customer.id}"
                       itemLabel="#{customer.name}" />
        <f:ajax render="customer-name" />
      </h:selectOneMenu>
      <h:outputText value="#{customerName}" id="customer-name" />
```

I put the `<f:ajax render="customer-name" />` into the select, but the outputText isn't updated. I didn't really expect it to, but...

**What do I need to do to get it to work?**

As the Facelets subview still has the same parameters as they were passed, how do I get "new ones" in? What's the best practice for this?

PS: pqHome is a `@ViewScoped` bean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dropdown only changes the ID of the customer, not the customer name. Even more, it does not change the whole customer entity at all. It only changes the ID of an existing customer. This is not good.

You need to change the code to let it set the whole customer instead of only its ID. E.g.

```
<ui:include src="/subviews/basedata-cpanel.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="customer" value="#{pqHome.pq.customer}" />
    <ui:param name="customers" value="#{organizationManager.allCustomers}" />        
</ui:include>
```

with

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{customer}" id="customer-select" converter="customerConverter">
    <f:selectItems value="#{customers}" var="c" itemValue="#{c}" itemLabel="#{c.name}" />
    <f:ajax render="customer-name" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:outputText value="#{customer.name}" id="customer-name" />
```

Don't forget to create a `Converter` which converts between customer ID and the `Customer` object and use it in the `<h:selectOneMenu>`.

Comment: Wow, I didn't believe this would work from a Facelets subview. It's always a good thing to **use entities instead of IDs/primitives**. Without your infamous article(s) http://balusc.blogspot.de/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ConvertingAndValidatingGETRequestParameters I wouldn't have gotten the CDI/EJB `converter="#{customerConverter}"` going! It can even handle nulls (no customers). Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome. You may find the [OmniFaces `SelectItemsConverter`](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2012/03/omnifaces-project-has-started.html#SelectItemsConverter) very helpful as well. No need for a EJB/DAO in your converter anymore.